# ajax-servlet; doGet method execute multiple times for a single ajax call

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets, soundmanager2

I used the sound Manager API to create a music player.

[tutoriel of creating playlist audio](http://fr.openclassrooms.com/informatique/cours/du-son-dans-vos-pages-web-avec-soundmanager-2/tp-un-lecteur-audio-3)

the player is in the form of a list of tags (a), and I want to apply a voting system for my songs.

every time I click on a link "a", a div appears (contains star) to give an evaluation and make the database update.

I use it for ajax and servlet:

ajax code:

```
function voter(){

    $('#informations .container .votes_main .votes_gray .votes_buttons a').click(function () {
        valide= true;
        var voteVal = $(this).attr('id');
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            contentType: "charset=utf-8",
            url:''+encodeURI('/RecommandationDefault/rating?vote='+voteVal),
            success:function(response){
                alert(response);
            },
            error: function(e){
                alert('Error: ' + e);
            }
        });
    });
return false;

}
```

servlet code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package votes;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(name="rating")
public class rating extends HttpServlet {


    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
            } 

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        int i=0;
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write("salut");
        i++;
        System.out.println("executé "+i+" fois");
    } 

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

when I click on a link and I vote, only one alert is displayed when I click afterwards on another song I would have "two alert", and so on.

Problem: I want one alert appears every time I vote

Comment: can you please post your html as well? My guess is that your selector is that when you click on the link to vote, the selector has two items. A very trivial example of this would be a div inside a div, both with the same class. $(".thatClass").click() would fire twice when you click on the inner div

Comment: after testing, the problem is not in ajax or doGet method , the problem is in SoundManager .

when I click play, the method lireCourant to execute and execute the method vote :

Comment: function lire_current() { 
 .........
        voter();
}

Comment: and the code of the method I vote : function voter(){
    
    $('#informations .container .votes_main .votes_gray .votes_buttons a').click(function () {
        alert("voter");
        ......
        });
    });
}

Comment: therefore , when I click on a link , only one alert is displayed when I click on another two alerts appears, then when I click on another three alert appears so on ...